# What is the best method for Software/Web Application Testing?

Tags: testing

Does any one know how to manage Software/Web Applications Testing process ?

Comment: Yes, someone knows. -- Now, I would recommend changing this question to be more specific... what kinds of problems are you having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hexawise test case generator can dramatically reduce your test design time (e.g., figuring out what combinations of browsers, configurations and functions should be tested so as to achieve maximum coverage in a manageable number of test cases).

Free trials are available at: http://hexawise.com/users/new

Disclosure: I created the tool based on the applied statistics-based Design of Experiments principles my dad, William G. Hunter, used to teach about when he was a professor at the University of Wisconsin.

/Slight tangent: it is surprising to me that Design of Experiments methods are widely used in manufacturing today, but rarely used in software testing. The same types of combinatorial explosions exist in both manufacturing (e.g,. thing about how many billions of ways there could be to manufacture a radial tire) and software testing (where billions of potential use cases exist in most non-trivial software applications particularly when browser types and/or configuration options are thrown into the mix).  These Design of Experiments methods dramatically improve efficiency in both situations (and are extremely easy to prove in software testing projects by simple "bake-offs"); despite this they remain unused in the vast majority of testing organizations, even at Fortune 100 firms.  I'm hoping to raise awareness and help change this. End of tangent/

- Justin

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of aspects to it, but one tool that is quickly becoming important in our arsenal is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to test multiple layers of your software. Unit tests cover the smallest segments of code, like a specific method's output, rather than the way methods interact. Then at the opposite range of the spectrum there is the integrated user experience testing, which mimics a user pressing buttons and doing things with your application (using a tool like Selenium if you're writing web applications).